# Not able to drag and drop in selenium webdriver using java either chrome or in FF

Tags: selenium, xpath, drag-and-drop

[image]I am working on automating a form designer, and I have to drag few fields to "Special fields" section. I am not able to drag fields to "Special fields" section. I have tried all the solution that was given in net, no luck. 
Xpath to "Special fields" section has fieldset as follows. Is it because of frameset in xpath that Drag and drop is not working?

Special section xpath: //div/fieldset[contains(@id,'formEditorTestFieldSet')]/div[contains(@id,'formEditorTestFieldSet')]

[image]
I have attached screenshot of HTML as well.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML, even partially with the code you've tried?

Comment: I have a framework specific method. That was not working. Also I tried following selenium one, still did not work.  Actions builder = new Actions(getWebDriver());
      builder.clickAndHold(FIELD).moveToElement(SPECIAL_FIELD).release().build().perform();

Comment: I have attached HTML screenshot in the question now. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this.
The `dragElement` is the one you need to move, take `xpath` , `id` or `cssSelector`. Here I used `cssSelector`.
Also, `dropElement` is the place you need to drop the selected element.

```
public void dragAndDropContent() {

     WebElement dragElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("drag element path"));

     WebElement dropElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("drop element path"));

    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(dragElement)
            .moveToElement(dropElement).release(dropElement).build();
    dragAndDrop.perform();

}
```

Also please check whether your switching to the particular window is correct or not. Hope it will help you :-)

Comment: Does the xpath you have formed highlights "Special section" using firepath? Are you seeing any exception? can you directly reach at special section as below `//div[contains(@id,'formEditorTestFieldSet')]`

Comment: @nandeshkalyankar In the special section you need to give the corresponding xpath,id or css path. you can use firepath or firebug to get the path as you mentioned.